Looking for children's book with gimmicky pages from the '70s
I remember reading a children's book from perhaps 1969 that featured a bunch of gimmicks among the pages. There may have been some pages with holes cut in them, or folded pages, things like that--but the only thing I remember with certainty was a scene of a traffic light at night, and the page before it was something like tracing paper. You could see the traffic light through the tracing paper. It was supposed to look like a foggy night.
I think the story was something about a child taking a journey. The images were all, I believe, full color drawings. More than that I can't recall. I read it in school, perhaps a fifth grade class, but it wasn't a textbook. It was just something that the teacher had for us to peruse.
EDIT as per Stuart F's suggestion: USA, New York State. I'd guess the book was about 8" x 10" or 10" x 14." I remember the illustrations having broad, flat areas of color, maybe not even with many outlines, as if they were made of pieces of cut-out colored paper. I don't remember anything that looked photographic/realistic. It seemed to be brand new in 1969.

The description of "pages with holes cut in them, or folded pages" sounds like almost any pop-up book, but those aren't usually aimed at 10-year-olds.

Pop-up books were well-established and popular by the late 60s, so almost certainly more info will be needed. Anything at all? Size, setting/nationality, artistic style (realistic or cartoonish), was it a new book in 1969? (While most pop-ups are for young children, there have been some for older children on slightly more mature themes and even for adults. Or it's possible you would keep a treasured pop-up book for older kids who would be less likely to destroy or eat it.)

@Stuart F - see edit above.
